# Virtual Machine Manager - Search for Virtual Machines by Running Time

Tags: powershell, virtual-machine, hyper-v

I'm using Virtual Machine Manager 2008 R2 and was wondering if any of you know how I might be able to search for virtual machines by running time.

I would like to find the machines that have been up and running the longest, so that I can go through and reboot any that have been up for over 6 months.

Perhaps using powershell this can be accomplished? Anything from within the GUI would be even better!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: Just found a better, and shorter, way:

```
Get-VM | Where-Object { (Get-VMPerformance -VM $_.Name).UpTime.Days -gt 180 } | Select-Object Name
```

You can get the information from each VM with WMI. This will give you all VMs running more than 6 months without a reboot:

```
$LastBootUpTime = (Get-Date).AddMonths(-6)

Get-VM | Where-Object { Test-Connection -ComputerName $_.Name -Count 1 -Quiet} | Foreach-Object{

    $os = Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $_.Name

    if( $os.ConvertToDateTime($os.LastBootUpTime) -lt $LastBootUpTime) { $_ }

} | Select-Object Name
```

Comment: Thanks for this, however I've never run a WMI script before. Do I use wmic to run this? Or do I plonk it into a .vbs file? I'm managing these VMs remotely from a Windows 7 machine if that helps? Thanks.

Comment: In VMM, click the PowerShell button (under the main menu), wait for powershell to open, then paste the script inside and press the Enter key to execute it.